# Laravel 4 and AmazonSES Emails not delivered

Tags: laravel, swiftmailer, amazon-ses

I had success setting up Laravel 4 mailer with AmazonSES smtp endpoints to send out emails using the Laravel default mailer and smtp.

This seems to work fine ( with most cases ).

We have a process that sends out approx 10k emails. But a few emails address are skipped and emails dont seem to get delivered to particular email addresses. I tried sending emails to 3 different email addresses of the same domain , which results in the mail never getting delivered to 2 email addresses. But the other one seems to work fine.

Same as for gmail addresses emails don't seem to get delivered to one particular email address. Apart from Geography there is no other common factor amoung the email accounts that don't receive the emails.

Any idea ? I am quite lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating the config/mail.php with the below worked

```
host => 'aws_end_point' // ie. email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com

username => 'your_aws_key'

password => 'your_aws_secret'
```